# How to solve $\int \frac{1}{\sqrt{\frac{C}{x^2}-1}}\;dx\;\;$

Tags: integration, indefinite-integrals

How does one  solve the following integral:

$$\int \frac{1}{\sqrt{\frac{C}{x^2}-1}}\;dx\;\;,$$

where $C$ is some constant. Should substitution be used here?

Comment: A difference of squares may suggest a trigonometric substitution.

Comment: [Euler substitutions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler_substitution)

Comment: $t=x^2$ is sufficient.

Comment: When math education will stop teaching the "trigonometric substitutions"? How many generations of students damaged!

Comment: up to rescaling, this essentialy the derivative of $\sqrt{1-x^2}$

Comment: If $C \leq 0$ the radical is negative. If $C > 0$, the domain of integrability is $-\sqrt{C} <x< \sqrt{C}$.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

$$
\int \frac{1}{\sqrt{\frac{C}{x^2}-1}}dx = \int \frac{1}{\sqrt{C-x^2}}\frac{1}{\frac{1}{x}}dx=\\
\int \frac{xdx}{\sqrt{C-x^2}}
$$
us the sub $C-x^2 = u$

Comment: Should be $|x|$ on top.

Comment: I don't claim this is wrong, but just that one should be a bit careful. $\sqrt{x^2}=|x|$.